# Change path for QgsAction icon in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, xml, file-path, actions

I added a `QgsAction` in my layer style, but when I share this style to other users, the path to the icon is written in absolute. I watched `QgsAction` doc ([here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsAction.html#qgis.core.QgsAction.iconPath)) and it doesn't seem to be a `setIconPath()`, neither in the C++ code.

Is there a possibility to modify it through `writeXml()` function ? How to use it ?

Here is the Action in QGIS :
[image]

and here is the QML corresponding :

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
<qgis styleCategories="Actions" version="3.22.5-Białowieża">
  <attributeactions>
    <defaultAction key="Canvas" value="{21c2fa36-51e8-4226-8412-c021e686edb9}"/>
    <actionsetting type="1" action="my code action" icon="/absolute/path/to/icon.svg" isEnabledOnlyWhenEditable="0" name="Modifier la couleur" notificationMessage="" id="{21c2fa36-51e8-4226-8412-c021e686edb9}" shortTitle="Modifier la couleur" capture="0">
      <actionScope id="Canvas"/>
      <actionScope id="Feature"/>
    </actionsetting>
  </attributeactions>
  <layerGeometryType>0</layerGeometryType>
</qgis>
```

Comment: The style is applied from a QML so I don't create it programmatically, I only apply it to my layer with `loadNamedStyle`. Appart from recreating the action with its class instantiation, there is no way to modify the icon path ?

Comment: Are you talking about a layer Action : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#actions-properties ? I didn't know that icons can be changed. So, to explain / describe it, can you share screenshots ?

Comment: I modified my question to show you how I change the icon. And when I save the style to a QML file, the path is written in absolute in the XML. I'm using QGIS 3.22 too.

Comment: In the source code, the full path is always saved, see : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/vector/qgsattributeactionpropertiesdialog.cpp#L174-L178

Comment: This could be an evolution as many file paths in QGIS are now editable / relatively saved.